# Error connecting AWS RDS MYSQL from AWS Lambda Node.js

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect AWS RDS Mysql from Lamda function written in Node.js. Initially I was getting "timed out" error, then I made below configuration.

-The Lambda execution role has full access to VPC.
-The Lambda function and the RDS instances are now in the same VPC.
-The Lambda function and the RDS instances are in same subnets.
-The Lambda function and the RDS instances shares a security group.
-All inbound traffic permitted.

Now I says that the DB I am trying to connect is unknown.Giving below error:

```
Response:
{
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'empdb'",
"trace": [
"Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'empdb'",
```

I am copying the code snippet as well.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

   var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
  user     : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  port     : process.env.RDS_PORT,
  database : process.env.RDS_DATABASE
});

connection.connect();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const sql = "insert into MESSAGE values('Testing1');";
  connection.query(sql, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    callback(null, '1 records inserted.');
  })
};
```

I tried both Create and Insert statements. I am new to AWS. Please advise.

Comment: Hi @Sri, if you ran that code outside lambda works ok?

Comment: Hi, I did the same coding now in Python and it is working fine. I used same subnet and security configuration.